# Disable the std::initializer_list constructor

Tags: c++

I am trying to work out if it is possible to disable the std::initializer_list constructor in certain circumstances. I am writing a custom vector class that support expressions (math and relational operators). The relational expression implicitly converts to bool to allow use in an if-statement but this is causing me problems with the constructors for my vector class (v5) in some cases where I want a vector result from the relational expression.

```
#include <vector>

struct expr
{
    std::size_t size() const { return 1; }
    auto at(std::size_t i) const { return 1.0; }
    operator bool() const { return true; }
};

template<typename T>
struct my_vec
{
    my_vec(std::initializer_list<T> init)
        : vec_{ init }
    {}

    my_vec(std::size_t sz)
        : vec_( sz )
    {}

    my_vec(expr e) 
        : vec_( e.size() )
    {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i != e.size(); ++i) vec_.at(i) = e.at(i);
    }

    std::vector<T> vec_;
};


void test_init_a(void)
{
    // initialize_list constructor
    my_vec<double> v1{ 1.0 };
    my_vec<double> v2{ 1.0, 2.0 };

    // size_t constructor
    my_vec<double> v3(5);

    // expression constructors
    expr e;
    my_vec<double> v4( e );
    my_vec<double> v5{ e }; // <-- this one attempts the initializer_list constructor because of the implicit cast to bool and fails due to narrowing
}
```

I could just always use the parenthesis to construct my vector from an expression (v4) but I wanted to figure out it it is possible to disable an initializer_list constructor at all?

I have tried is to implement a wrapper to the initializer_list and use double brace initialization, however this then causes single-element access a problem (v1) as it tries to use the size_t constructor instead of the initializer_list constructor.

Answer (score 4):

> I wanted to figure out it it is possible to disable an initializer_list constructor at all?

You can't.  This is how the language works and if you used braced initialization and you have a `std::initializer_list` constructor then that is one that is called.

What you can do though is remove the implicit conversion that is allowing the `std::initializer_list` to be created in the first place.  If you make `expr::operator bool()` `explicit` then `e` can't be converted to `bool` which means the only suitable overload is now `my_vec(expr e)`

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, you can make the constructor template, then apply SFINAE to make it unusable when the type in `std::initializer_list` is not same as the template parameter `T` of the class.

```
template <typename X, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<X, T>>* = nullptr>
my_vec(std::initializer_list<X> init)
    : vec_{ init }
{}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ylUijKE4NWdphlO0)